# How to use material-ui module for communicating two projects?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

My main project contains two projects: **front-end**, and **component** project. we design custom components into the component project and use it into the front-end project. Both projects use to the [material-UI module](https://material-ui.com/) that adds to the package.json file.

My problem is that, when I used to [IconButton component](https://material-ui.com/api/icon-button/#iconbutton-api) in the front-end project, it destroys style's Button into the component project or any material-UI component that extends of MuiButtonBase.

As shown below, **MuiButtonBase-root** override CSS style on **makeStyles-withIcon-194**

[image: Display css style]

How to solve this problem?

Is there a problem with the theme config?